# Multivariate Gaussian distribution - Covariance vs linear dependence

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, anomaly-detection, gaussian

From prof. Andrew Ng's Multivariate Gaussian distribution lecture, covariance measures linear dependency between features, in which case we might use Multivariate Gaussian distribution with covariance matrix. And also, if features are redundant (for ex: x1= 2 * x2; clearly linear dependency exists between features), covariance matrix is not invertible and can't use Multivariate Gaussian distribution with covariance matrix. For me, these statements looks contradictory.

 
Question:
Whats difference between covariance - linear dependency and features linear dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is a multivariate Gaussian distribution, the covariance matrix is a measure of the linear relationship between the features.

If one feature is a linear combination of other features, the data can still assumed to be a multivariate Gaussian distribution. However, since there is the linear dependence the matrix is singular and the inverse can not be calculated.

Comment: Just want to note that the non-invertibility does not need to be a problem in practice (and certainly not analytically.) For example you can still sample from the degenerate MVN using the SVD of the covariance matrix. This is the reason behind the `allow_singular` argument fo `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal()`.